What is local.retention.bytes in the Kafka topic configuration?
I noticed a new setting in Conduktor Console which I think has been added recently.
It is called local.retention.bytes. There is also an associated local.retention.ms.
Here is what the documentation says about this parameter:

The maximum size of local log segments that can grow for a partition before it deletes the old segments. Default value is -2, it represents retention.bytes value to be used. The effective value should always be less than or equal to retention.bytes value.

But what does this mean? In particular, what is a "local log segment"? My guess would be that perhaps if this broker is part of a cluster, this value describes the maximum quantity of disk space for this broker which a topic log can occupy?
I tried to verify this information by searching the docs (and google) but I couldn't find the answer.
ChatGPT 4o (which is effectively a search engine) says this about it:

In Kafka, a local log segment is a portion of a topic partition's log that is stored on a single Kafka broker's local storage.

However, ChatGPT is unreliable, so this could be completely made up. I only really included it for your interest.
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#local-retention-bytes

That gpt answer is correct, but tiered storage features is after its trained dataset

The local.retention.bytes configuration is relevant when tiered storage is enabled. Tiered storage allows Kafka to offload older log segments to a cheaper storage medium while keeping more recent segments on local storage for faster access.  local.retention.bytes helps manage the size of the local storage a topic uses.
The difference between retention.bytes and local.retention.bytes is that retention.bytes controls the maximum size a partition can grow to before old log segments are discarded to free up space. On the other hand, local.retention.bytes specifies the maximum size of local log segments for a partition before old segments are deleted.
Reference: Tiered Storage Configurations
